# How to make tf.data.Dataset only shuffle a subset of data column?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Let's see we have a dataset:

```
   ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train ))
```

if I apply ds = ds.shuffle(), then both x_train and y_train will be shuffled. How to do if I only want shuffle x_train while keeping y_train unchanged?

Comment: Just curious to know the reason of doing that because if you do that feature vector will be mapped with wrong label.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what u want with a map function that returns only 1 of the outputs. And then you can zip them.

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
ds_x = ds.map(lambda x, y: x)
ds_y = ds.map(lambda x, y: y)
ds_x = ds_x.shuffle(buffer_size=50) #change buffer_size as u like
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds_x, ds_y))
```

Comment: thanks, first shuffling one dataset then zipping with the other dataset works.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this since wrong labels will be mapped to the features. 
But still if you want to do this anyways, you can shuffle `x_train`, before feeding it to `from_tensor_slices()`.